# matlab videoplayer which matlab compiler supports

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

Compiler producing .exe in Windows does not support "vision.VideoPlayer" in Computer Vision System Toolbox 7.0.
Is there other video player which Matlab compiler c an use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `vision.DeployableVideoPlayer`.

Comment: Thanks, Dima
  Compiled and run correctly by replacing "vision.VideoPlayer" with your answer as "vision.DeployableVideoPlayer" after compiling with "mcc -mv vidPlay.m"